# Checkbox list in columns via JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, checkbox

How can I create a layout with a set of checkboxes evenly distributed into columns at the top of a page? I'm using jQuery and classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS and HTML:

```
    #checks_container {
      width:600px;
      overflow:auto;
    }

    .check{
      float:left;
      width:100px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="checks_container">
  <div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="myname" value="1" />One</div>
  <div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="myname1" value="2" />Two</div>
  <div class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="myname2" value="3" />Three</div>
</div>
```